# How can I programmatically delete frames from an mpg video and keep the audio in sync?

Tags: ffmpeg

I stream training videos from work, but don't have a great connection and get a lot of buffering. I have captured the streamed video from the PC screen into an mpg file. Fortunately when the video buffers, it shows a characteristic buffering icon in the center of the screen and there is no sound. Using ffmpeg, I have been able to write a c++ method that can step through the video frames of the mpeg file, convert to an RBG frame and detect the presence or absence of this characteristic buffering icon.

The final thing I need to do is generate a new mpeg file with only the frames that do not have this buffering image, and keep all the audio in sync. How do I do that with ffmpeg?

I have already found the dts and pts timestamps on the video and audio frames, but don't know how to use this information to recode just the frames that don't have the buffering image. The recode should keep all the properties of the original (framerate, resolution, size etc)

Here is the stripped down code I use to traverse the frame and detect which ones I want to keep (omitting a lot of initialization and error checking)

```
while (av_read_frame(pFormatCtx, &packet) >= 0)
    {
        // Is this a packet from the video stream?
        if (packet.stream_index == videoStream)
        {
            // Decode video frame
            avcodec_decode_video2(pCodecCtx, pFrame, &frameFinished, &packet);

            // Did we get a video frame?
            if (frameFinished)
            {
                // Convert the image from its native format to RGB
                sws_scale(sws_ctx, (uint8_t const * const *)pFrame->data, pFrame->linesize, 0, pCodecCtx->height, pFrameRGB->data, pFrameRGB->linesize);
                if (ThisIsAFrameIWant(pFrameRGB))
                {
                    WRITE FRAME TO NEW MPEG KEEPING AUDIO IN SYNC
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This will require some expertise.
1st if you not already did you should create new output context with video and audio stream (i.e. mpeg2+mp2).
My experience says in case of problematic streams (as you have) you can forget pts/dts thing (some other dudes out there who knows better be my guest..). Instead you may keep video and audio in separate buffers (the incoming packets after `av_read_frame()`). For this look for `ffplay` it has `videoqueue` and `audioqueue` in some structure, use it.
For the audio you need to some processing before queuing. Trick is audio frames (or packets you obtained with `av_read_frame()`) if not equal to `audio samples per frame` you should do it manually with additional buffering. For example 16 bit 48000hz pcm16 audio for 60hz video should have 48000/60 = 800 audio samples per frame. If you can manage this. It will be easy to keep a/v in sync, just make sure audio and video has same number of packets in buffer. So if you drop a video packet, do same for audio.

2nd do not use RGB for any known video algorithm (mpeg2, h264, hevc) to encode video packets. Use yuv420p. This will same some trouble.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Wow yes, great help. - thank you. I use RBG because I figured out how to access the pixels directly from that format. This allows me to apply my detection algorithms when I am deciding to keep a frame or not. Is is possible to interrogate the frame directly for pixel info without going through RGB. This would actually save quite a lot of time.

Comment: As far as I know `sws_scale` doesn't write source buffer, it uses separate buffer for destination, so keep RGB for detection and source yuvframe for mpeg stream as is. Or if you wanna more work, research on OpenCV, it actually designed for (or has functionality for) this kind of `image processing` job.